# Django Add to Cart Button Returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have an add to cart button in my Django Application. When i click to add to cart button i get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error but the product is added to cart. I am able to see my cart when i click to cart link that placed right top on my page but i can not see it when i click to add to cart button. It goes to nothing. What might cause this problem ? any help would be appriciated.

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    # get product slug from post data, return blank if empty
    product_slug = postdata.get('product_slug','')
    # get quantity added, return 1 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',1)
    # fetch the product or return a missing page error
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug) #django shortcuts helper method
    #get products in cart
    cart_products = get_cart_items(request)
    product_in_cart = False
    # check to see if item is already in cart
    for cart_item in cart_products:
        if cart_item.product.id == p.id:
            # update the quantity if found
            cart_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            product_in_cart = True
    if not product_in_cart:
        # create and save a new cart item
        ci = CartItem()
        ci.product = p
        ci.quantity = quantity
        ci.cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        ci.save()
```

Comment: You're missing a return in this function, and it seems like you have 500 handler that might terminate the entire request without a response.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I am new in Django and compeletely lost about your answer.

Comment: Consider starting with a tutorial, then : (

Answer (score 0):

You should return a resonse. for example like this:

import `render_to_response` by:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
```

And use it in your view:

```
return render_to_response( 'your_template')
```

also take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

Comment: I made this change but i am getting cookies must be enabled error. My cookies are enabled already though.

Comment: I use cloud9 and i get this error above add to cart button in my page.

Comment: I think it is not related to django